# Difference between using Printf() and return in Ternary Conditional (?:) operator

Tags: c, operators, ternary-operator

Say i write:

```
   int a=1,b=2;
   a<b ? return 1 : return 2 ;  // Case 1
```

it gives Compile Error Saying "error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’"

But when i write:

```
   int a=1,b=2;
   a<b ? printf("1\n") : printf("2\n"); // Case 2
```

This Successfully compile and give output as expected.

Even i tried this :

```
a<b ? printf("1\n"): return 2;
```

I thought may be the reason was because in case return 1 doesn't have ";" to end his line of statement.

but Only case 2 is successfully. what is different in CASE 2 from CASE 1 ? is it control transfer?
Please Explain !

My compiler - C 4.3.2 Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("1\n")
```

is an expression

but `return` is a statement.

The C conditional operator requires C expressions for all its operands.

You can just use:

```
#define MIN(a, b)  ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

return MIN(a, b);
```

if your goal was to return the minimum of the integers.

Comment: oh ! i forget that defintion of ?: is 

condition ? expression1 : expression2 

Thanks !